# Unity 5 play 2D animation one time

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I need to play animation just one time.

Something like this:

```
public Animation[] animations;

animations[0].play();
```

I've looked through StackOverflow, all I found is:

```
animation["AnimationName"].wrapMode = WrapMode.Once;
animation.Play("AnimationName");
```

But it makes nothing. 
Is this method actually for Unity3D 5?
Are there new ways to play animation one shoot?

Comment: Alex 'But it Makes nothing' mean Animation is not playing or Animation is playing continuously

Comment: Animation is not playing. I've marked animation as "legacy", but animation is not playing, console shows no error.

Answer (score 2):

I have one way for playing animation on mouse down.

For that open animator controller and add that dropping animation and one will be idle animation(this will have initial stage of dropping). Now make idle animation as default and add transition from idle to dropping animation.

Add parameter to this transition of type "Trigger". Set this parameter in transition condition.

And add one more transition from dropping animation to idle state.

So after dropping animation complete , it will come again in idle state.

Now For scripting :

```
int dropHash = Animator.StringtoHash("parameterName");
```

onmouseDown :

```
animator.SetTrigger(dropHash);
```

Hope you get some idea. This may help you. Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean Idle, instead of Ideal?

Comment: Yes means idle animation

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `wrapMode`. In your case, it can be something like

```
foreach(Animation anim in animations) {
    anim.wrapMode = WrapMode.Once;
    anim.Play();
}
```

Comment: I made it. Animation is not playing.